# Print/log everything that pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal() finds

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following test. Its purpose is to detect - given a tolerance - any differences between two dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

def test_two_cubes_linewise() -> None:
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5.0], "B": [4, 5, 6, 7, 8.0001]})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [97, 98, 3, 4, 5], "B": [99, 5, 6, 7, 8.0002]})
    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2, rtol=1e-3, check_dtype=False)
```

[pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html) works perfectly for that. There are several differences between df1 and df2:

- `5` and `5.0` are different dtypes.
- `1` is not equal to `97`.
- `2` is not equal to `98`.
- `4` is not equal to `99`.
- `8.0001` is not equal to `8.0002`.

As the last difference is below the tolerance, the assert statement only detects the other differences - as wanted. However, when I run the test, the assertion error message only shows the first difference:

[image: pytest screenshot]

Any suggestions on how to access the information which are all differences respectively?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to handle any exception by yourself.

Let's take a look at the assert_frame_equal signature:

```
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(
    left,
    right,
    check_dtype: "bool | Literal['equiv']" = True,
    check_index_type: "bool | Literal['equiv']" = 'equiv',
    check_column_type: "bool | Literal['equiv']" = 'equiv',
    check_frame_type: 'bool' = True,
    check_names: 'bool' = True,
    by_blocks: 'bool' = False,
    check_exact: 'bool' = False,
    check_datetimelike_compat: 'bool' = False,
    check_categorical: 'bool' = True,
    check_like: 'bool' = False,
    check_freq: 'bool' = True,
    check_flags: 'bool' = True,
    rtol: 'float' = 1e-05,
    atol: 'float' = 1e-08,
    obj: 'str' = 'DataFrame') -> 'None'
```

As you can see it's setting `check_dtype=True` by default, which is preventing the other checks to take place. I'd suggest to modify your code as follows:

```
import pytest
import pandas as pd

@pytest.mark.parametrize("check_dtype", [False, True])
def test_two_cubes_linewise(check_dtype) -> None:
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5.0], "B": [4, 5, 6, 7, 8.0001]})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "B": [5, 5, 6, 7, 8.0002]})

    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2, rtol=1e-3,  check_dtype=check_dtype)
```

Changes include passing a boolean flag to the test, so we can easily test switch from check_dtype=[True -> False]. Refer to the pytest docs for more details https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/parametrize.html

And then you can run `pytest --no-header`

```
> pytest --no-header
============================================================= test session starts ==============================================================
collected 2 items                                                                                                                              

the_pandas_test.py FF                                                                                                                    [100%]

=================================================================== FAILURES ===================================================================
________________________________________________________ test_two_cubes_linewise[False] ________________________________________________________

check_dtype = False
    
>       pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2, rtol=1e-3,  check_dtype=check_dtype)

the_pandas_test.py:9: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
testing.pyx:55: in pandas._libs.testing.assert_almost_equal
    ???
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

>   ???
E   AssertionError: DataFrame.iloc[:, 1] (column name="B") are different
E   
E   DataFrame.iloc[:, 1] (column name="B") values are different (20.0 %)
E   [index]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
E   [left]:  [4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0001]
E   [right]: [5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0002]
E   At positional index 0, first diff: 4.0 != 5.0

testing.pyx:173: AssertionError
________________________________________________________ test_two_cubes_linewise[True] _________________________________________________________

check_dtype = True
    
>       pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2, rtol=1e-3,  check_dtype=check_dtype)
E       AssertionError: Attributes of DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] (column name="A") are different
E       
E       Attribute "dtype" are different
E       [left]:  float64
E       [right]: int64

the_pandas_test.py:9: AssertionError
=========================================================== short test summary info ============================================================
FAILED the_pandas_test.py::test_two_cubes_linewise[False] - AssertionError: DataFrame.iloc[:, 1] (column name="B") are different
FAILED the_pandas_test.py::test_two_cubes_linewise[True] - AssertionError: Attributes of DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] (column name="A") are different
============================================================== 2 failed in 0.54s ===============================================================
```

You might want to check the other flags for better results.

Comment: thanks, your answer was helpful. I edited the question to clarify what exactly I am looking for.